# How to go up a line in Console Programs (C++)

Tags: visual-c++, animation, console-application

In C++ I'm trying to go back up a line to add some characters.
Here is my code so far:

```
cout << "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\xc9\xbb\n\xc8\xbc"<<flush;
Sleep(50);
```

As you can see, I have 10 newline characters. In my animation, a new block will be falling from the top of the screen. But I don't know how to go back up those lines to add the characters I need. I tried \r, but that dosen't do anything and \b dosen't go up the previous line either. Also, what exactly does flush do? I've only been programming in C++ for about 2 days so I'm a newb =P.

Thanks so much!!!

Christian

Answer (score 17):

If your console supports [VT100 escape sequences](https://web.archive.org/web/20151004211730/http://www.termsys.demon.co.uk/vtansi.htm) (most do), then you can use `ESC [ A`, like this:

```
cout << "\x1b[A";
```

to move the cursor up one line. Repeat as necessary.

Comment: I'm using Visual C++ 2010. When I use that, the console just displays a left arrow and then "[A". If I change "[A" to hex code and try it, I just get another error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Oh I see, you're using Windows. VT100 escape codes work pretty much everywhere *except* Windows. Sorry about that.

Comment: Windows doesn't really have good support for console mode programs at all. If you're just learning and don't *need* to use Windows, try installing a Linux VM and doing it there.

Comment: @43.52.4D. if you are trying to practice c++, linux will be great for you as there are tons of readily accessible open-source libraries that you can integrate into your program. In windows you are pretty much on your own. Using existing libs is also much harder in windows. Also the gcc compiler that linux ships with gives much comprehensive error messages than vc++ making it easier to know what went wrong.

Comment: On windows, you'll more than likely have to roll your own console library. Look up console buffers; they're actually *easier* to use as far as changing lines than linux, though a lot clunkier and 'hack-ish'.

Comment: Just saying, the link is dead.

Comment: @DarthPaghius: Link has been resurrected.

Answer (score 4):

In windows you can use this [example](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/228811-microsoft-using-console-functions-to-achieve-blinking-text/)

there you will create CreateConsoleScreenBuffer()
and then are using SetConsoleCursorPosition(console_handle, dwPosition);

Answer (score 0):

`cout` will first write to internal buffer and only output it to the screen periodically and not for every character that gets inserted. This is for performance reasons.

`flush` tells it to empty the buffer now and show it on screen.

You should  consider a library like [ncurses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses).