# C++ Multiple Choice with Arrow Keys

Tags: c++

I am wondering how to make a multiple choice prompt in the console where you can select the options with the arrow keys. So instead of something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string selection;
    std::cout << "A. option 1";
    std::cout << "B. option 2";
    std::cin >> selection;

    if(selection == "A") {
        //do whatever;
    } else if(selection == "B") {
        //do something else;
    } else {
        //repeat the prompt
    }
return 0;
}
```

I could have something that looks like this, but without the fancy UI:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wtyhk.jpg)

Comment: Well, I don't think you can with `cin` or anything standard for the matter. This "fancy UI" seems to be ncurses; you could use it for your program.

Comment: Yep, from the image it is [ncurses](https://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/). you don't want to implement such stuff portably based on `iostream` facilities on your own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is by no means an all encompassing answer, but i'm hoping it will help with the basic idea.

I wrote up a quick C++ program which preforms the logical part of a multiple choice picker using only the up arrow, down arrow, and enter key.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>//For _getch().

//https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24708700/c-detect-when-user-presses-arrow-key
#define KEY_UP 72       //Up arrow character
#define KEY_DOWN 80    //Down arrow character
#define KEY_ENTER '\r'//Enter key charatcer

int main(){
    int selected = 0;    //Keeps track of which option is selected.
    int numChoices = 2; //The number of choices we have.
    bool selecting = true;//True if we are still waiting for the user to press enter.
    bool updated = false;//True if the selected value has just been updated.

    //Output options
    std::cout << "A. Option 1\n"; 
    std::cout << "B. Option 2\n";

    char c; //Store c outside of loop for efficiency.
    while (selecting) { //As long as we are selecting...
        switch ((c = _getch())) { //Check value of the last inputed character.
            case KEY_UP:
                if (selected > 0) { //Dont decrement if we are at the first option.
                    --selected;
                    updated = true;
                }
                break;
            case KEY_DOWN:
                if (selected < numChoices - 1) { //Dont increment if we are at the last option.
                    ++selected;
                    updated = true;
                }
                break;
            case KEY_ENTER:
                //We are done selecting the option.
                selecting = false;
                break;
            default: break;
        }
        if (updated) { //Lets us know what the currently selected value is.
            std::cout << "Option " << (selected + 1) << " is selected.\n";
            updated = false;
        }
    }
    //Lets us know what we ended up selecting.
    std::cout << "Selected " << (selected + 1) << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24708700/c-detect-when-user-presses-arrow-key) stack overflow answer to determine how to track key presses in the console.
[This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10058050/how-to-go-up-a-line-in-console-programs-c) answer may also prove useful for moving the console cursor around when changing the background color of text.

Good luck!